# numpy.loadtxt ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python, numpy

```
import matplotlib 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np
import time

dt = 'i4,i4,i4,a5,f9'
month,day,year,time,price = np.loadtxt('spyTestTest.txt', 
delimiter='  ',dtype = dt)
```

I am trying to run this code on some sample data (below)

```
8 18 2014 9:30 196.79

8 18 2014 9:31 196.8249

8 18 2014 9:32 196.825

8 18 2014 9:33 196.88

8 18 2014 9:34 196.887

8 18 2014 9:35 196.835

8 18 2014 9:36 196.81

8 18 2014 9:37 196.81

8 18 2014 9:38 196.81
```

However I am getting an error saying

Value Error: too many values to unpack.

I read online that this occurs when you have more variables than columns to parse, but it looks to me like I have 5 variables and 5 columns of text. Any advice?

Comment: If you literal texts looks like you posted, with spaces in between, then `np.loadtext` will read `\n` and try to unpack it to 5 values and fail. If, however, that's just because of poor formatting edit your question further to represent **exactly** how it looks.

Comment: dont use `time` as a variable name. you are overwriting `time` module that you are importing.

Comment: you can also use the `struct` library to do this type of thing and avoid numpy https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html

Comment: did you check the answer below?

Answer (score 4):

as your input file already formatted use **unpack=True**, this should solve your problem

```
month,day,year,time_k,price = np.loadtxt('spyTestTest.txt', delimiter=' ',dtype = dt, unpack=True);
```